# Как сделать элементы RecyclerView накладываемыми друг на друга?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Нужно сделать элементы RecyclerView в виде карточек нестандартной формы, с учетом свайпа влево.
Элементы списка, должны как-бы накладываться друг на друга.
Элементы списка в виде карточек с обрезанный верхним левым углом, верхняя часть элемента имеет тень, создавая эффект наложение на предыдущую карточку.
При свайпе влево, выдвигаются элементы (красный и серый прямоугольник), при этом сохраняется тень внизу.

[image: Карточки]

Comment: Вы сломали мой мозг :) Отличный вопрос!

Comment: из изображения вообще ничего не понятно

Comment: @Sviat Volkov, а вы не смотрите на верх :)

Comment: Попробуйте использовать ItemDecoration

Comment: Проблема в том, ItemDecoration не подвергается свайпу, и фон верхней части карточки зависит от цвета предыдущей карточки. Также на часть, которая открывается во время свайпа, накладывается тень от верхней части следующей карточки.